# Allow user to control access to own content for other authenticated users

Tags: 8

I just want a field in a content type, so that when a user creates new content he/she can select whether that content can be viewed by other authenticated users or not. I prefer doing this with a selection field displaying 'hidden/visible' to other users and then set the actual access in a custom module using some hook.

This is what I tried so far in my custom module hook entity access with content type test_adgang and checking field_test_adgang, but no effect, meaning all authenticated users can still see, if field set to 'skjult' (hidden).

```php
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;


function import_functions_entity_access(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, $operation, \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account) {
    if ($entity->bundle() == 'test_adgang') {
        if ($entity->field_test_adgang->value == 'skjult' && $operation == 'view' && in_array('godkendt bruger', $account->getRoles())) {
            return AccessResult::forbidden();
        } elseif ($entity->field_test_adgang->value == 'synlig' && $operation == 'view' && in_array('godkendt bruger', $account->getRoles())) {
            return AccessResult::allowed();
        }
    }
    
}

?>
```

Comment: You aren't returning the result of your hook. That's one problem. Check the docs of the hook you are using.

Comment: Thanks, return was missing, works now :-)

Answer (score 1):

The [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module allows you to specify if users can view the node. The first setting is for the content type, but there is a setting there to allow that to be set on a per node basis. You can look at using that module, or look at what they're doing to solve this.